# Shopping carts and concurrency in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just starting to look at building a shopping cart, and one of the issues that has come up in designing it is what do to in this scenario - say Product A has a remaining stock level of 5.  Then Customer A reaches the page where they can select the quantity they require and they select 3.  But they have yet to confirm the order/make payment etc.  Then Customer B comes to site and selects a quantity of 4.  Then the problem arises that if both customers then confirm their orders, one of them will encounter an error as the stock level will have been reduced after they made their selection.  What is the standard way to handle this?  Is it to perhaps create an 'On Hold' field and add to it every time a user selects a quantity, so that that stock is set aside until they confirm or cancel?  What if they don't cancel but just leave the site?

Just looking for a few pointers from anybody who may have already dealt with this issue.

Comment: I would avoid an on-hold flag as any bugs in the system could leave you with lots of products incorrectly on hold (you could have a timeout, but its just extra complexity). I would opt for a simple check upon confirm of purchase with a simple message like: "Sorry, we no longer have this item in stock - try to be a bit quicker next time!"

Comment: Have you considered existing products? An example http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/ Maybe you can get some stuff from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take into account "stock reservations" when calculating the available stock for a certain product. You decide when to put a certain shoppingcart line into "Reservation" mode and when you "release" it again.

I've implemented a store where stock is **"reserved" at the moment a user starts a payment** and it is **"released" when the user cancels the payment** or **"issued" when the payment succeeds**.

Don't forget to double check the available stock when it is reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

until the user does not confirm the order, you shouldnt reserve the stock. 
If I buy a product before you, you should get a message telling you that someone has already bought it, or simply that there isnt enough stock

It'll free you for lots of headaches

Answer (score 0):

What i under stand is 
You want to implement shopping card and you facing an problem while more then one user logged and tray to buy things :)

Here is solution .. 
The problem arise because shopping card is share between user.
you can just maintain a tmp list for shopping card for logged user.
and while they ready to pay add it in shopping card  and show details.

Note : You have to handle stock while doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest you would be to not lock the user item till he reaches the Order confirmation page with a a suitable lock duration marking the item reserved for a specific duration before which the order should be complete or else the items are reflected back in the inventory. If you look at the [Amazon Cart help page](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=540842), here is what it says

> Placing an item in your shopping cart doesn't hold the item for you.
> An item is only reserved for your order after you click the Place your
> order button and receive e-mail confirmation that we've received your
> order.

An extreme case would be to not reserve till the final order is complete, or reserve only when you reach the payment page.

You need to minimized the blocking window and handle scenarios where there is a conflict (by providing backorder option)